# xHCI combined with KVM switch causing USB controller to crash

Tags: usb, kvm-switch

I'm currently troubleshooting a fairly interesting issue going on with my at-home work setup. My setup consists of a microphone, headset, microphone and mouse (all USB2.0 devices). Three of these devices go into a passive (bus-powered) USB hub, which in its turn goes into a KVM switch I use to switch the devices between my own PC and the work computer. The fourth USB device simply goes straight into the KVM. This is done because the KVM switch only supports 2 USB devices by itself.

The KVM switch is actively powered via a MiniUSB port (but noteworthy the USB hub isn't). With xHCI disabled, this seems to work. However, with xHCI enabled, there seems to be a 2-3 times-per-day incident where the USB controller seem to malfunction, causing all USB devices to go down. This was noticed when I had to enable xHCI in order to connect a USB3.0 based adapter and things started to behave very oddly.

I'm unsure whether this is a USB controller (on motherboard-level) that is starting to become old, or if the unpowered USB hub is what is causing too much stress on the controller, which in it's turn is just about surviving with xHCI (and as such the functionality and additional power draw of the USB3.0 ports) disabled?

**Finding 1:** Enabling xHCI on my main computer (as opposed to work computer) seems to be working without issues, at least during my test. Work computer is a HP Z440 (guessing a pretty generic motherboard) and main PC holds an Asus Z97K.

**Finding 2:** Enabling xHCI on my work computer, and bypassing the KVM/USB-hub entirely seems to work. Also seems to work if only the USB hub is bypassed but the KVM is still used (though this is, as of writing this, being tested). I guess my going theory is that the USB controllers of my own PC are sufficient enough to power the entire array of devices, while the same cannot be said for my work computer. Though if this is plausible or not I have no idea. Furthermore, I still do not quite understand why/where/how this is dependent on xHCI, as the only physical ports I currently use are non-blue (USB2.0).

**Another finding:** Referring to the diagram below, if the web camera is connected to my personal PC, I get a warning saying there is not enough USB resources to power this device (or something along the lines). The work PC also seems to malfunction/freeze a lot faster in meetings/calls where everything is being used, as opposed to other tasks that doesn't require the microphone, headset, or camera to really be used. I still do not know what xHCI has to do with any of this, but I am seriously starting to consider a powered USB hub, and considering the fact that the current power usage is simply "on the limit", and sometimes (ie. with the web camera on), that limit is breached.

[image: Setup diagram]

Comment: Yes; The problem is likely directly linked to that USB 3 device being connected to anUSB 2 port. Which normally wouldn’t be a problem but your going through a low performance USB 2 hub

Comment: @Ramhound The only USB3.0 device that is connected to a USB2.0 port is the unpowered usb hub. The additional USB3.0 device I mentioned was connected to a USB3.0 port, but as xHCI was enabled, I could not keep it enabled.

Comment: Yes, and I am suggesting the reason you were unable to leave it on, is due to the fact the KVM does not support USB 3 and thus the downgrade to USB 2 is the issue. If you were directly connecting to the USB hub on the machine itself, that downgrade might not be a problem, but I am suggesting it is due to the use of the KVM.

Comment: @Ramhound I see. However, even so, the KVM switch is plugged into a USB2.0 port on one of the ports on the back side of the computer, so should that be a concern at all? I could fully see your reasoning if I had it plugged into a USB3.0 port.

Comment: What you describe screams aUSB resource problem caused by the KVM you have, but that’s just me personally, I might be totally off base

Comment: @Ramhound Had xHCI enabled on my own computer (as compared to the work computer) last night with no issues, and the connection between the hub, KVM and computer looks exactly the same there (but with another computer/motherboard of course). Now attempting to have xHCI enabled on my work computer, but bypassing the KVM/Hub, to try to find some kind of pattern.

Comment: Can you clarify which devices have what kind of connections? e.g. is the KVM connected to the computer via USB 3.0 or USB 2.0?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Entirely valid question, I'll update the original post showing the current setup shortly.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... 1) how does the KVM behave when you switch the KVM away from a computer – do the KVM USB mouse and keyboard completely disappear or do they still show up as present on that computer? 2) do you happen to have a non-3.0 hub to test with?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Judging off of device manager, the devices completely disappear (at least on my own PC) when the KVM is switched. Unfortunately, the USB hub I use is the only one I'm able to test with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems using a powered USB hub (see diagram for "USB Hub (bus-powered)" was the solution to this problem - or at least have been, for the last 3 days. I have currently replaced the USB hub with a Transcend TS-HUB3K and it seems to be working this far (unless it is all a coincidence, of course).